# How do you prove a number is not normal to any base?

Tags: normal-number

If you allow for bases to be real numbers, it is not guaranteed that natural numbers have a terminating expression. So is there a way to prove, that a number is not simply normal to any given base? Or is maybe even every number normal so some real base? How could you prove or disprove such a statement?

Comment: Of bases for what are you talking? What is a "terminating expression?

Comment: You might find my paper [Absolutely abnormal numbers](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/index.shtml?abstract=AAN) interesting—it discusses exactly this kind of question.